# Refresh a fragment from Activity using hide/show or detach/attach

Tags: android

I'm trying to refresh the content of 2 fragments in my activity after an update done in my DB.

I saw some answers telling to use hide/show or attach/detach but it doesn't work for me...maye be I'm doing something wrong...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

taken from here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution using two container in my layout (and replace each of them by a "refreshed" fragment) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kmel maybe i can help you if you present logs here. start logcat and copypaste a part with your components of it here